# How to deploy windows container from docker-cli with aci support?

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances, windows-container

I need to deploy a windows container from docker-cli, for my linux containers it is ok and they are working (with some caveats...) but not for window containers.

CLI Command:

```
docker --context my-context run -p 80:80 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
```

Answer

```
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ Group thirsty-murdock  Error                                                                                                                        
containerinstance.ContainerGroupsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="ImageOsTypeNotMatchContainerGroup" Message="The container image 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp' doesn't support specified OS 'Linux' for container group 'thirsty-murdock'."
```

Is there any way to set os-type from docker-cli with ACI support? Or will I need azure-cli?

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc
- https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#what-windows-base-os-images-are-supported
- https://blog.alexellis.io/run-iis-asp-net-on-windows-10-with-docker/

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you running this command and on which OS? If you are running Docker on your local desktop you can only use Windows or Linux containers - not both.

Comment: Locally, I'm working with Ubuntu, but I though that I could run "remotely" windows containers from my ubuntu to ACI, because I am not building any image, just pulling and running on docker remote... :-(